# Laravel - Event based on relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have the following models.

1. `Shipment`
2. `ShipmentPiece`

A `Shipment` can have multiple `ShipmentPiece` instances. A `ShipmentPiece` belongs to a `Shipment`.

---

Is there a model event (same as `creating` or `saving`) for when I attach a new `ShipmentPiece` to a `Shipment`?

For example, when I do:

```
$shipment->shipmentPieces()->save($shipmentPiece);
```

or

```
$shipment->shipmentPieces()->saveMany([$piece1, $piece2]);
```

I would like to run some logic in the `Shipment` class, inside the `boot` method.

Comment: Since you're already accessing $shipment to save the item, couldn't you just add a method on Shipment to save the piece and run the logic you want to perform?

Comment: I can but you could use that same logic for replacing "Model Events" and not use them altogether.

Comment: I would normally use events to react to changes from other objects, not the same object.   To answer your question, I don't believe there are any events for saving a related item, except for the creating/saving on the related model.

Comment: Why can you not use the `created` or `saved` on the `ShipmentPiece` to dispatch an event, e.g. `ShipmentPieceSaved`, and register a listener to act upon that event, and update the `Shipment` as required?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2303

Comment: Thanks @MunteanuPetrisor and fubar. I solved this issue with the Event/Listener pattern!